# извлечь подстрочку с помощью sed

Tags: linux, sed

третий час сижу, не получается(
помогите с помощью sed извлечь номер строчки 247634 из строки

`61/817313536]" \n1604871715,"tester",24: (at row 247634)`

такое вот регулярное выражение не находит ничего:
`(?<=\(at\ row\ ).*?(?=\))`

Comment: `\(at row (\d+)\)` ?

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так:

```sh
echo '61/817313536]" \n1604871715,"tester",24: (at row 247634)' |\
    sed -e 's/.*(at row \([0-9]*\).*/\1/'
```

```
247634
```